# Not getting expected results from included files in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I'm not getting expected results by including files in Nodejs. Here is my code:

**Service Route File**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const path = require('path');
const config = require('../config');
const serviceAdapter = require('./serviceAdapter');

module.exports = (preRequestPath, serviceBaseUrl) => {

    console.log("On server start", preRequestPath)

    router.post('/*', (req, res) => {

      console.log("On request", preRequestPath)

      const axiosHttp = serviceAdapter(serviceBaseUrl);

      axiosHttp.post(preRequestPath+req.path, req.body).then(resp => {
        res.send(resp.data)
      }).catch(err => {
        res.status(404).sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/../404.html'));
      });
    });

    return router;
}
```

**Main Server File**

```
const express = require('express');

const userApiService = require('./routes/userService');
const userAdminService = require('./routes/userService');

app.use('/api/user_service/', userApiService("/api", config.userServiceUrl) );
app.use('/admin/user_service/', userAdminService("/admin", config.userServiceUrl) );

var server = app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('Server listening on port 3000');
});

module.exports = server;
```

**Expecting Console Result:**

```
On server start /api
On server start /admin

On request /api         (when hitting http://baseurl.com/api/<anything>)
On request /admin       (when hitting http://baseurl.com/admin/<anything>)
```

**But Getting Console Output as:**

```
On server start /api
On server start /admin

On request /api         (when hitting http://baseurl.com/api/<anything>)
On request /api       (when hitting http://baseurl.com/admin/<anything>)
```

Both the time, returning /api path. 
Can anyone tell me why is it happening and what's the solution?

Comment: The code you've shown in your question does not match the output you say that you see.  Your routes are hooked up to `/api/user_service/` and to `/admin/user_service/` so I don't see how  `http://baseurl.com/api/<anything>` or `http://baseurl.com/admin/<anything>` matches either of them unless the anything happens to be "user_service".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating only one router in `userService.js` (the first file). It's created once before the function so you really only end up with one router.  The first time you `require` it the router gets created, but the second time you `require` it Node knows it was already loaded and it's not re-initialized. You should be creating a different router for each case like this:

```
const express = require('express');
// const router = express.Router();  <-- don't do it here
const path = require('path');
const config = require('../config');
const serviceAdapter = require('./serviceAdapter');

module.exports = (preRequestPath, serviceBaseUrl) => {
  const router = express.Router();  // <--- create a new router for each case
  console.log("On server start", preRequestPath)

  router.post('/*', (req, res) => {
    console.log("On request", preRequestPath)

    const axiosHttp = serviceAdapter(serviceBaseUrl);

    axiosHttp.post(preRequestPath+req.path, req.body).then(resp => {
      res.send(resp.data)
    }).catch(err => {
      res.status(404).sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/../404.html'));
    });
  });

  return router;
}
```

Also in your main server file you only need to require it once. It's just a function to create the service so you don't need 2 different variables holding that function. So you can initialize both using the one function like this:

```
// const userApiService = require('./routes/userService');
// const userAdminService = require('./routes/userService');
const service = require('./routes/userService');

app.use('/api/user_service/', service("/api", config.userServiceUrl) );
app.use('/admin/user_service/', service("/admin", config.userServiceUrl) );
```